# Django login/authentication system not really working

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm a newbie in django and I'm having some problems, what I'm trying to do is a simple login system in Django with a custom backend and using postgresql as the main db.

The problem is, my authentication and login function is apparently working normally but the user is not actually logged in, I wrote a custom message to let me know when the user is logged in and my index is protected against anonymous user, so I basically can't access.

This code from my *views.py*

```
@login_required(login_url='signin')
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def signin(request):
    now = datetime.now()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        print(username, password)

        user = UserBackend.authenticate(UserBackend(), username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user, backend='core.backends.UserBackend')
            print('Logged In') #### This print/checking is working fine!
            return redirect('/')  
            #return render(request, 'index.html')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Invalid Username or Password! Try again')
            return redirect("signin")
    #else:
        return render(request,'signin.html')

    
    #user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    return render(request, 'signin.html')
```

This is my user class from *models.py*

```
class user(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.TextField()
    real_name = models.TextField()
    email = models.TextField()
    password = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    last_login = models.DateField()
    created_at = models.DateField()
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user'
        
   
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.username
```

And my user backend from *backends.py*

```
class UserBackend(ModelBackend):

    def authenticate(self, **kwargs):
        username = kwargs['username']
        password = kwargs['password']

        print('user: ', username)
        print('pass: ', password)
        #try:
        user_ = user.objects.get(username=username)
        
        try:
            print(user_.check_password(password))
            if user_.check_password(password) is True:
                return user_
        except user.DoesNotExist:
            pass

        def get_user(self, user_id):
            try:
                return user.objects.get(pk=user_id)
            except user.DoesNotExist:
                return None
```

I tried changing the return on *views.py* to something like

```
 return redirect(request.GET.get('next'))
```

but still not working :(

what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The key point, is how you are using your Backend. Although, lets start from the beginning...

Starting with your models, you are unnecessarily overwriting a lot of fields. Django's `AbstractUser` has these fields you are creating. In fact, the model contains the following fields with validators where appropriate:

1. username
2. first_name
3. last_name
4. email
5. is_staff as default false
6. is_active as default true
7. date_joined as default `timezone.now()`
8. last_login
9. a built-in function `get_full_name` (equivalent to your `real_name` field)

Also, `id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)` is not necessary Django by default creates this kind of field automatically for every model. Most of the times used when you want a different kind of field as PK. Thus a simple model, would fulfill your requirements:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    description = models.TextField()
```

The [backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) is pretty straight forward, check credentials and return an User object instance if everything is correct. `ModelBackend` already has a `get_user` method defined.

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class UserBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, **kwargs):
        username = kwargs['username']
        password = kwargs['password']
        
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            pwd_valid = check_password(password, user.password)
            
            if  pwd_valid:
                return user
            else:
                return None
            
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Now, about on how to use it. Quotting the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends):

> Behind the scenes, Django maintains a list of “authentication
> backends” that it checks for authentication. When somebody calls
> django.contrib.auth.authenticate() Django tries authenticating across
> all of its authentication backends. If the first authentication method
> fails, Django tries the second one, and so on, until all backends have
> been attempted.
>
> The list of authentication backends to use is specified in the
> AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS setting. This should be a list of Python path
> names that point to Python classes that know how to authenticate.
> These classes can be anywhere on your Python path.

So, first we need to add AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS in settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'core.User'
LOGIN_URL = '/signin'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'core.auth.backends.UserBackend', 
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
]
```

And lastly in views.py, we call the functions exactly as you would in a normal [login](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in) function:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib import messages

# Create your views here.
@login_required
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def signin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            # Confirm that backend is UserBackend
            print(user.backend)
            return redirect('core:index')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Invalid Username or Password! Try again')
            return redirect("core:signin")

    return render(request, 'signin.html')
```